# Convert a one-to-many relationship to many-to-many and update existing references

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a one-to-many relationship which I've converted to a many-to-many relationship.

Example:

```
Main Table (
   Id int,
   Code varchar(2)
)

Secondary Table (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(250),
    MainId int
)
```

I have the following entries in the Main table:

```
Id Code
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

Secondary table:

```
Id Name MainId
1  Foo  1
2  Bar  1
3  Foo  2
4  Bar  2
5  Bar  3
```

Since the values in the column 'Name' in the 'Secondary' table are repeated quite often, the db size has grown considerably, I've decided to convert into a many-to-many relationship and only reference unique 'Name' entries.

As a first step I've created the following join table:

```
MainSecondary Table (
   MainId int,
   SecondaryId int,
)
```

For the final step I need to update the existing references and delete duplicate records based on the 'Name' column, which is where I'm stuck (over a million records).

The intended outcome should be:

Main table:

```
Id Code
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

Secondary table:

```
Id Name
1  Foo
2  Bar
```

MainSecondary table:

```
MainId SecondaryId
1 (A)  1 (Foo)
1 (A)  2 (Bar)
2 (B)  1 (Foo)
2 (B)  2 (Bar)
3 (C)  1 (Foo)
```

Comment: You could just make name a FK

Comment: Assuming that the `Code` and `Name` values are unique: Create the three new tables and add `distinct` values for `Code` and `Name` to `Main` and `Secondary`. (Indexes would be a good idea.) Then add the `MainSecondary` rows as needed from the `join`ed original and new tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-up

```
create table main 
(
   id      int,
   code    varchar(2)
);

create table secondary 
(
    id       int,
    name     varchar(250),
    main_id  int
);

insert into main (id, code) values (1, 'A');
insert into main (id, code) values (2, 'B');
insert into main (id, code) values (3, 'C');

insert into secondary (id, name, main_id) values (1, 'Foo', 1);
insert into secondary (id, name, main_id) values (2, 'Bar', 1);
insert into secondary (id, name, main_id) values (3, 'Foo', 2);
insert into secondary (id, name, main_id) values (4, 'Bar', 2);
insert into secondary (id, name, main_id) values (5, 'Bar', 3);
```

Create new_secondary table

```
create table new_secondary
(
    id       int,
    name     varchar(250)
);
```

Create new relationship table: main_secondary

```
create table main_secondary 
(
    main_id       int,
    secondary_id  int
);
```

Populate new_secondary table, removing duplicates

```
insert into new_secondary
(
    id,
    name
)
select
    min(id),
    name
from
    secondary
group by
    name;
```

Populate main_secondary relationship table

```
insert into main_secondary
(
    main_id,
    secondary_id
)
select distinct
    a.main_id,
    b.id        as secondary_id
from
    secondary  a
    join 
    new_secondary b
    on a.name = b.name;;
```

Check the results

```
select 
    a.id    as main_id,
    a.code,
    c.id    as secondary_id,
    c.name
from
    main a
    join 
    main_secondary b
    on a.id = b.main_id
    join
    secondary c 
    on c.id = b.secondary_id;
```

Results

```
main_id     code secondary_id name
----------- ---- ------------ -------
          1 A               1 Foo
          2 B               1 Foo
          1 A               2 Bar
          2 B               2 Bar
          3 C               2 Bar
(5 rows affected)
```

3 (C) 2 (Bar) is different from your example, but I think it's correct.

You would need to drop the old secondary table and rename the new_secondary table (when you are sure everything is OK) to keep things tidy.